# NginX proxy_read_timeout TCP connection status

Tags: nginx

When NginX is configured as a reverse proxy and gives up waiting for the following reasons

- proxy_read_timeout
- proxy_connect_timeout
- proxy_send_timeout

it sends a 504 gateway timeout to the client. What does it do with the TCP socket it had open, or was trying to open to the upstream http server e.g. Apache? Is it re-used by another incoming request or does it close it?

Answer (score 1):

nginx is well built, and certainly closes everything when the final 504 status is established.